# Maximum Number of horizontal asymptotes of a Rational function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The maximum number of horizontal asymptotes  a Rational function can have is 1 according to [Thomas calculus 14th edition](https://www.amazon.in/Thomas-Calculus-George-B/dp/9353060419).

The only reasoning I could come up with is:

given a function f(x)/g(x), if the degree of f(x) is one more than g(x) , then it will have an oblique asymptote, if it is two or more than the degree of g(x) then no horizontal asymptotes.
if the degree of g(x) is more than that of f(x) then the only horizontal asymptote possible is y=0.

This reasoning does not seem concrete enough, can somebody explain exactly why a rational function have at most one horizontal asymptote.

Comment: If there's a horizontal asymptote, it's $\lim_{x\to\infty}f/g$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f/g$, and those two limits are equal.

Comment: Your reasoning is on the right track. Don't forget the case where the degrees are equal.

Comment: If the degree of $f$ is higher  than the degree of $g$, the limits at infinity are infinite and there is no horizontal asymptote. So, you can focus on the case  where the degree of $f$ is less or equal than the degree of $g$. Just see what happens when the degrees are equal and when they are not equal. In both cases you get a single horizontal asymptote.

Comment: There are (unique) polynomials $p(x),q(x)$ with $f(x)=p(x)\cdot g(x)+q(x)$ and $deg(q)<deg(g)$ Divding by $g(x)$ , we get $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=p(x)+\frac{q(x)}{g(x)}$ and $\frac{q(x)}{g(x)}$ tends to $0$ if $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$, therefore $p(x)$ is the (unique) nonvertical asymptote. If it is a constant, it is horizontal.

Comment: @DavidMitra - you mean no *rational* function can have more than one asymptote, of course. There are plenty of functions of other types with two asymptotes, such as $y = \arctan  x$.

Comment: @David, Paul's example does have two horizontal asymptotes. $\arctan x$ has different limits as $x\to\infty$ and as $x\to-\infty$, unlike rational functions.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Of corse, silly me.